# Parsing a Markdown style link safely

Tags: php, regex, xss, markdown

I have written some code to match and parse a Markdown link of this style:

```
[click to view a flower](http://www.yahoo.com/flower.html)
```

I have this code that is meant to extract the link text, then the url itself, then stick them in an A HREF link. I am worried though that maybe I am missing a way for someone to inject XSS, because I am leaving in a decent amount of characters. is this safe?

```
$pattern_square = '\[(.*?)\]';
$pattern_round  = "\((.*?)\)";

$pattern = "/".$pattern_square.$pattern_round."/";

preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);
$words = $matches[1];
$url   = $matches[2];

$words = ereg_replace("[^-_@0-9a-zA-Z\.]", "", $words);
$url   = ereg_replace("[^-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:.]","",$url);

$final = "<a href='$url'>$words</a>";
```

It seems to work okay, and it **does** exclude some stupid URLs that include semicolons and backslashes, but I don't care about those URLs.

Comment: The ereg library is deprecated for years, you should really switch to preg.

Comment: there are a dozen+ php markdown parsers, why not use one of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already passed the input through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) (which you ***are*** doing, right?) then it is already impossible for the links to contain any characters that could cause XSS.

If you have not already passed the input through `htmlspecialchars`, then it doesn't matter what filtering you do when parsing the links, because you're already screwed, because one can trivially include arbitrary HTML or XSS *outside* the links.

This function will safely parse Markdown links in text while applying `htmlspecialchars` on it:

```
function doMarkdownLinks($s) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/', function ($matches) {
        return '<a href="' . $matches[2] . '">' . $matches[1] . '</a>';
    }, htmlspecialchars($s));
}
```

If you need to do anything more complicated than that, I advise you to use an existing parser, because it is too easy to make a mistake with this sort of thing.